# Why ZrO2 reservoir is useful for reducing tungsten's work function in Schottky field-emitters?

Tags: electrons, electronic-band-theory, metals, thermoelectricity

Schottky emitters (field-assisted thermionic emitters) use a tungsten filament for thermionic emission, as well as barrier lowering electric field to reduce the effective work function of the filament.

Commercial tips are made of <100> tungsten crystal, and a ZrO2 reservoir that is said to be useful in reducing tungsten's <100> work function.

But if the emission is at the tip apex (pure tungsten, far from the zirconia), how the zirconia reservoir is capable of lowering the effective work function at the apex? (And why the whole tip is not made out of ziroconia in the first place?)

[image]([source](http://www.tnw.tudelft.nl/index.php?id=33723))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because zirconium oxides increase in electrical conductivity at higher temperatures, which essentially lowers the energy barrier for electrons to move around, lowering the energy required to get them to the tip. It also preferentially lowers the work function of the tungsten (100) surface which lowers the spread of the beam of a <100> oriented filament.

The reduction in work function from Zr comes from monolayers of Zr covering the entire emitter. The large agglomeration of Zr in the middle of the tip acts a s a reservoir to replenish any evaporated sites of Zr.

Comment: electrons are extracted from the tungsten tip, which is far from the zirconia, so how does it help in reducing the work function..?

Comment: I don't know for certain but, from what I've read, the reduction in work function from Zr comes from monolayers of Zr covering the entire emitter. The large agglomeration of Zr in the middle of the tip acts a s a reservoir to replenish any evaporated sites of Zr.

Comment: sounds right. Mind moving this to the answer?

Comment: I've added the comment.